# Android: Listview with Webview not clickable

Tags: android-webview

i have a activity which extends ListActivity. The Layout contains some generic widget an a custom widget derived from a WebView:

```
<com.Android.myPrj.myWidget
                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:id="@+id/mywidget"
                 android:layout_width="200px"
                 android:layout_height="35px"
                 android:focusable="false"
                 android:clickable="false"
                 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
             />
```

When I set visibility to GONE or when i remove the custom widget everything is ok. But if the widget is drawn i cannot click the element. Not even onListItemClick is invoked. What can I do?

thanks
Tata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView is buggy in ICS. I had to explicitely set

```
    mWebView.setFocusable(false);
    mWebView.setClickable(false);
```

to get the job done. XML seems to have no effect.

Comment: thats not buggy thats what its ment to do! WebView receives touch events

Comment: But when it receives touch events that come from *outside* WebView, it IS buggy.